Adding significant difference from GLM?
In R, I am looking at a dataset with calculated total abundances(Totals) in a month across multiple years. Data was collected from multiple sites within each year; the years were categorized into two separate groups(i.e. warm or cold) depending on the mean temperature.  The data is not normal so GLM(negbin) was used to determine significance between groups and across temperature of the years. p value for temp was significant. If a plot was made showing the mean abundances for each year, how would you add the significant differences for the years to the plot?
Data would look essentially something like this:
library(tidyverse)
library(glmmTMB)

set.seed(123) 
n <- 72
fake_years <- sample(2000:2020, size = 12, replace = FALSE)
fake_group <- tibble(
  Year = fake_years,
  Temp = round(runif(12, min = -10, max = 40), 1), 
  Group = sample(1:2, 12, replace = TRUE) 
)


fake_data <- fake_group %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 6)) %>% 
  mutate(Site = sample(paste0("Site", 1:5), n, replace = TRUE), 
         Totals = round(runif(n, min = 0, max = 1000), 1))

fake_bmir<-fake_data%>% 
  group_by(Year)%>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Totals),num_obs=n(),sum_year_totals=sum(Totals),
            sd_year_totals= sd(Totals),se_mean=sd_year_totals/sqrt(num_obs),
            se_upper=mean+se_mean,se_lower=mean-se_mean)
fake_bmir<-fake_bmir %>% 
  mutate(Group=if_else(Year=="2000"|Year=="2004"|Year=="2010"|Year=="2017",1,0))
#GLM
NB1<- glmmTMB(Totals~ Group+Temp,
              family=nbinom2, data=fake_data) 
#Basic plot
ggplot(fake_bmir, aes(x = factor(Year), y = mean, fill = factor(Group))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = se_lower, ymax = se_upper), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  labs(title = "Mean Totals by Year with Standard Error", x = "Year", y = "Mean Totals", fill = "Group") +
  theme_minimal()

I don't quite understand how to add the differences to multiple bars on a plot. My desired output is to show years that had some level of significant difference to them.

More of a comment for Cross Validated, but there's a lot to unpack in "the data is not normal". In general you shouldn't use a negative binomial response for non-integer data (you should have gotten a warning from glmmTMB) unless you know what you're doing/are sure that's the right choice. You might want to look around on Cross Validated/ask a question there about what to do ...

I apologize, that is my fault. The fake data generated created non-integer data, but the actual data is only positive integers since its from ecological counts

OK, then a negative binomial sounds like it's probably a reasonable choice.

At the moment I don't see the purpose of the regression model if you want to plot descriptive statistics in your plot. You could also try to plot adjusted predictions (expected values of your outcome) at meaningful levels of your predictor(s) of interest and then do pairwise comparisons. You could do this with several packages, including ggeffects (predict_response() and test_predictions()), marginaleffects (predictions() and hypotheses) or emmeans (emmeans() and pairs()).

Assuming that you want to fit the same model (Totals ~ Group + Temp) separately for each year, you could start like this:
p_val_info <- (fake_data
  ## split data by year
  |> split(fake_data$Year)
  ## fit model to each chunk
  |> map(\(d) glmmTMB(Totals~ Group+Temp, family=nbinom2, data = d))
  ## extract coefficients/p-vals/etc. for each model, aggregate to a single df
  |> map_dfr(\(m) broom.mixed::tidy(m, effect = "fixed"), .id = "Year")
  ## keep only relevant stuff
  |> select(Year, term, estimate, p.value)
  ## convert Year back to numeric in case we want to merge
  |> mutate(across(Year, as.numeric))
  ## we're not usually interested in the significance of the intercept term ...
  |> filter(term != "(Intercept)")
)

(It would be more idiomatic to use nest/unnest and operate on list-columns ...)
This leaves us with a data frame with p-values for Group and Temp (and the estimates) for each year. Since your sample data set is so small, all of the values are NA — either your real data set has observations with multiple values of Group and Temp within each year, or (alas) I don't understand the question (i.e., I don't know what you could "show years that had some level of significant difference to them" if within-year tests are impossible ...).
Once you've gotten this far you can

further reduce the data with some combination of group_by() and summarise() (e.g. do you want the minimum p-value for the effects for each year?)
merge this information with fake_bmir (via full_join(..., by = "Year")
use geom_label() or geom_text() with the x and y determined by the Year and top of the error bar in fake_bmir

The ggpubr package has some machinery for automatically adding p-values to a plot (e.g. based on pairwise contrasts of groups), but I doubt it can handle a case like this automatically ...
